Facing "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction with unauthorized signer or writable account" error in Solana Anchor program
I'm working on a Solana program using the Anchor framework. The program implements a simple counter that can be incremented or decremented by a user. The program compiles and deploys successfully, but when I call the increaseCounter or decreaseCounter functions from the frontend, I encounter the following error:
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction with unauthorized signer or writable account

Source Code: Github
#[program]
pub mod counter {
    use super::*;

    pub fn increase_counter(mut ctx: Context<ManageCounter>, step: u64) -> Result<()> {
        if ctx.accounts.counter.to_account_info().data_is_empty() {
            initialize_counter(&mut ctx)?;
        }

        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;

        msg!("Increasing counter by {}...", step);
        counter.count += step;
        msg!("Counter successfully increased. New value: {}", counter.count);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn decrease_counter(mut ctx: Context<ManageCounter>, step: u64) -> Result<()> {
        if ctx.accounts.counter.to_account_info().data_is_empty() {
            initialize_counter(&mut ctx)?;
        }

        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;

        if counter.count >= step {
            msg!("Decreasing counter by {}...", step);
            counter.count -= step;
            msg!("Counter successfully decreased. New value: {}", counter.count);
        } else {
            msg!("Cannot decrease counter below 0. Current value: {}", counter.count);
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument.into());
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}

fn initialize_counter(ctx: &mut Context<ManageCounter>) -> Result<()> {
    let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;

    msg!("Initializing counter with value 0...");
    counter.authority = *ctx.accounts.authority.key;
    counter.count = 0;
    msg!("Counter initialized.");

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ManageCounter<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [b"counter", authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<Counter>(),
    )]
    pub counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Counter {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub count: u64,
}


In the frontend, I use the following React code to interact with the Solana program:
  const increaseCounter = async () => {
    if (!program) return;
    try {
      const [counterPda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from('counter'), wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()],
        programID
      );
      await program.methods
        .increaseCounter(new BN(1))
        .accounts({
          counter: counterPda,
          authority: wallet.publicKey,
          system_program: SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();
      getCounter(program);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error increasing counter:', err);
    }
  };


can you post a signature of a failed transaction please ? will check which signature is missing... and does it fail when you initialize the PDA, or when you try to increase/decrease only ?

The error occurs when creating the PDA for the first time (i.e. when using init_if_needed). I can't share it because I couldn't get a transaction signature.
{
"signature": "",
"transactionMessage": "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account",
"transactionLogs": [
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
"Progr ...
" Instruction: IncreaseCounter",
"2pXCEyxopRZNhABaqQ3JefqPoeEycaUJuEFaDH4iLFwd's writable privilege escalated",

ok, you can get a signature if you put skipPreflight = true in config for sending the transaction. 2pXCEyx => which account is it ? is it your id.json ? user ? pda ?

i didn't know that thx, tx signature:
2ZnJWjqo38i3f7YtLP44LmPRqAtC9U1F9DvAbL8YUBpd9KxQpfsBifZF4DSJQqg9JRFoiHWW5d7Z5a8c9DdF6FNf
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2ZnJWjqo38i3f7YtLP44LmPRqAtC9U1F9DvAbL8YUBpd9KxQpfsBifZF4DSJQqg9JRFoiHWW5d7Z5a8c9DdF6FNf?cluster=devnet
2pXCEyxopRZNhABaqQ3JefqPoeEycaUJuEFaDH4iLFwd this pda calculated by client
  const [counterPda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from('counter'), wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    programID
  );


add an answer, too long for a comment ;)

just an idea: it looks like the tx fails when the account is created (CPI to system program), my idea is that your account is not sent as writable in your accounts array in the instruction. Could you check your IDL, you will find the instruction, and the related accounts. You have 2 params for each account: is signer, and is mutable (i don't remember the name exactly, but you will find it easily). Check if is mutable = true or false. if it's false, try to change it to true, and run again your script without modifying anything.
Also, i never used init_if_needed, might be related. What happen if you try with "init" only ? (if it works, it's only once, but it's to check if it's related to init_if_needed). May be with init_if_needed you need to manually add "mut" in the account (it doesn't look like it, but we never know...) ? My idea is that without "mut" attribute for the PDA account in the instruction's struct, the account is not flagged as writable in the IDL.

I encountered issues with writable and signer parameters, and also tried using init instead of init_if_needed, but the same error persisted.Yes the issue might be related to the IDL because each time I build, the type gets included in the generated types, and I receive an error in the frontend: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'kind')." I need to add the type manually to the account each time. Also, need to change pubkey to publicKey.
Below, I’ve included a GitHub link where you can find the frontend program and IDL file.
https://github.com/0xfiraterdem/counter

The issue was caused by the IDL file generated during the build with Anchor CLI not being in the correct format. I don't know the reason for this; I've updated all the packages to their latest versions, but the problem still persists. However, when I built it through https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/hello-anchor and used the IDL generated there, the program worked without any issues.

nice! good job!

As the error suggests, make sure that you are using the correct signer when sending the tx.
By default, the .rpc method uses the local Solana  ~/.config/solana/id.json wallet to sign for transaction.
Check that it is similar to the wallet signer you are using.
If different, you can first convert the method call into a transaction and sign it
await program.methods
    .increaseCounter(new BN(1))
    .accounts({
        counter: counterPda,
        authority: wallet.publicKey,
        system_program: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .transaction();

await signTransaction(tx);


I'm using Phantom Wallet for signing transactions on the client side, not the local wallet (~/.config/solana/id.json). The setup is meant to create a unique PDA for each user. When a user interacts with the program to increase or decrease the counter, it checks if their PDA exists and creates it if necessary. The program owner and the user’s wallets are different, so that might explain the issue.

updated my answer

Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account.
Logs:
[
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
i got this error
